# SQL way to index across tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Is there a way to create a multi column index across tables?

For example, if I had the following tables:

```
Foo (Table Name)
  FooID (PK)
  BarID (FK)
  FooName

Bar (Table Name)
  BarID (PK)
  BarName
```

I can do a

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foo 
LEFT JOIN Bar ON Foo.BarID = Bar.BarID
WHERE 
  FooName < "Bob"
  AND BarName > "Smith";
```

In this case, I want a multi column index against `Foo.FooName then Bar.BarName`.

I did some research but wasn't able to find anything, perhaps I'm not using the right terms. My question may depend on the SQL engine, in which case I'm interested in MySQL specifically, but I am interested in any other engines as well.

Doing the multi column index on Foo with the Foreign Key doesn't help, as the underlying value of its Name is what I want for the speed.

Comment: you can't. indexes are per-table. just put separate individual indexes on the two fields and move onwards.

Comment: You could if you create a [materialized view](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) however; and used it for queries.  but @MarkB is right, you can't do it across tables without other intervention.  But Materialized Views have other considerations and add to complexity of solution.

Comment: Note that your example query is an implicit INNER JOIN because you have `AND BarName > "Smith"` in the WHERE clause.  This should be `AND (BarName > "Smith" OR BarName IS NULL)` to retain the LEFT JOIN.  Alternately, you can put the `AND BarName > "Smith"` in the ON clause and filter before the JOIN.

Comment: Looks like MySQL has view ability too, however one of the restrictions is no indexing on views... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-restrictions.html :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Came across my own post years later and figured I could add some details, in case others have similar issues. As Mark B pointed out, each index is per table, however we can set things up that make this efficent, see below.

There are a couple of different things going on here, so can use indexes to help accomplish what we need. We need an index to help filter the main table, then an index that works well for the join and filter of the 2nd table. To help accomplish this, we can create the following 2 indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_fooname ON Foo (FooName);
CREATE INDEX idx_barid_barname ON Bar (BarID, BarName);
```

Once those indexes are in place, a query can be used like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foo USE INDEX(idx_fooname)
LEFT JOIN Bar USE INDEX (idx_barid_barname) ON Foo.BarID = Bar.BarID
WHERE 
  FooName < "Bob"
  AND BarName > "Smith";
```

Answer (score 2):

Smells like "over-normalization".  Might it be worth moving those two fields into the same table?

Akiban was an Engine that could do cross-table `JOINs`, etc.  But it no longer exists.

"Materialized Views" do not exist in MySQL (unless you implement them yourself).

Answer (score 0):

As xQbert mentioned, you can use materialized views (or indexed views if you use Microsft SQL Server).

But first you have to change your `LEFT JOIN` to a `INNER JOIN` (because of materialized/indexed views can't handle outer joins. The left join does not seem to make sense in your query because of the `WHERE ... BarName > "Smith"`.

That link might help you if you use SQL Server: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-indexed-views-the-basics/

After you created a materialized/indexed view, you can query the view directly (i'm not sure if the query optimizer will use it automatically).
Be aware that the materialized/indexed view will reduce your performance when you `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE` into the used tables (what every index will do, too). The best idear is only to add the realy neccesary fields to the materialized/indexed view.